# How can I solve issue with One to One relationship using foreign keys

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've been using eloquent in my models. I've got the following two tables:

```
Singlecard
  ->id
  ->card_id

Card
  ->id
  ->card_id
```

My Singlecard Model has the following function:

```
public function info()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Card', 'card_id', 'card_id');
}
```

I used this to get the card (there's only one card in the deck for my test).

```
$cards = Singlecard::where('deck_id', '=', $deck)->get();

foreach ($cards as $card) 
{
    $cards_array[] = $card;
}
```

It got the correct card and using var_dump I verified that. However, here's the problem:

```
<div class="row singlecard">
    <a class="" href="{{ $single->id }}">
        <div class="large-2 columns">
            <img src="{{ $single->info->card_image }}">
        </div>

        <div class="large-10 columns">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <p>{{ $single->info->name }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                @foreach ($single->attributes as $attribute)
                    <p>{{ $attribute->alias }}</p>
                @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here's the twist: The attributes code works correct. It grabbed the correct attributes from a one to many relationship I defined. But it's grabbing the wrong info from the Cards table. Even though I defined the keys to match on, it is matching based on the ID of the singlecard and the card_id in the Cards table.

I've tried removing the keys and that didn't do anything. I even removed the function all together just to verify that that was the function being called. I'm not sure what's wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I figured it out, I did two things. One, I used id from the Cards table as the record to match with Singlecards. I also changed my function in the Singlecards model like so:

```
public function info()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Card', 'card_id');
}
```

This allowed me to properly query the relationship.

Comment: Why are you referring to `card_id` instead of `id`?

Comment: Card_id is the unique id of the card info. Those two match up with each other. It's a little confusing. In the card table, id is the row number and card_id refers to the id of the card. In singlecard,  id is the unique id of the card and card_id matches up to the card_id row in the card table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to update how my models were related and better form the relationship. I also needed to change the model so that Singlecards belonged to Cards. I assumed it should be the opposite.

Cards contains all the info about the various cards and Singlecards is what is in each individuals hands/decks. I assumed that would make Singlecards the parent but that was a mistake. Once I changed the function in the model to be like this:

```
public function info()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Card', 'card_id');
}
```

Then it worked.